# custom palette not working in react js material ui

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to customize the palette colors for my project but I'm able to use only main attribute of it and not other. I am using MUI under JavaScript not Typescript

```
import './App.css';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes} from 'react-router-dom'
import Navbar from './components/Navbar/Navbar';
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';
import Home from './components/Home/Home';
import Contact from './components/Contact/Contact';
import Pricing from './components/Pricing/Pricing';
import About from './components/About/About';

const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      light: '#f5f6fc', //highlight
      main: '#f6f6f6',  //site bg gray...this works (light, dark doesn't)
      dark: '#000629',   //navbar items
      contrastText: '#fff', //main text large font
    },
    
    secondary: {
      light: '#cdd0d9', //paragraph text dark gray
      main: '#dce6ff',  // for content bg light blue......this works (light, dark doesn't)
      dark: '#ba000d',  //hover buttons
      contrastText: '#000',
    },
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For adding multiple primary/secondary colors, you'll need to use [custom variables](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/theming/#custom-variables).

Replacing `primary` to `myPrimaryColor` or something of your choice will make it custom variable which can be used down the line.

```
const theme = createTheme({
    myPrimaryColor: {
        success: 'green',
        danger: 'red',
    },
});
```

followed by

```
`theme.myPrimaryColor.success`
```